# Tridion Sites 9.5 with DXA 2.2 and DXA Model Extension dxa.properties configuration

Tags: dxa, content-delivery, dxa2.2

Just to share this question and answers with other community users.

In Tridion Sites 9.0 DXA 2.0 with Model Service implementation, we had an option to control not to remove the extension and strip-index-path for the component link resolver in the model service.

It was done by applying the following flags in the **dxa.properties**:

```
dxa.web.link-resolver.remove-extension=false
dxa.web.link-resolver.strip-index-path=false
```

Now, We have upgraded to Tridion Sites 9.5 with DXA 2.2 and used the DXA model extension, and deployed via add-on service.

DXA Model Extention deployed in Content Service and works as PCA APIs.

My question is How and Where is this config managed for this setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did investigate and found that it was still possible to manage **dxa.properties** in the /config folder of the content service for on-premise setup.

In case if you are using cloud and docker container setup, then it's possible to pass as environment variables for containers.

Interestingly also found that this config was embedded into this **udp-content-dxa-extension-11.5.0-1074.jar** in the add-on DXA model extension package.

Here is the configuration and variables placed in the OOTB DXA Model extension:

```
## Defaults settings
# Remove XMLNS attributes from Rich Text?
dxa.defaults.rich-text-xmlns-remove=${DXA_DEFAULTS_RICH_TEXT_XMLNS_REMOVE:true}
# Resolve TCM URIs into links in Rich Text?
dxa.defaults.rich-text-resolve=${DXA_DEFAULTS_RICH_TEXT_RESOLVE:true}
# Remove extension .html from resolved link?
dxa.web.link-resolver.remove-extension=${DXA_WEB_LINK_RESOLVER_REMOVE_EXTENSION:true}
# Strip /index at the end of resolved links?
dxa.web.link-resolver.strip-index-path=${DXA_WEB_LINK_RESOLVER_STRIP_INDEX_PATH:true}
## Error handling configuration
# Whether so suppress errors related to keyword expansion in a model
dxa.errors.missing-keyword-suppress=${DXA_ERRORS_MISSING_KEYWORD_SUPPRESS:true}
# Whether so suppress errors related to entity expansion in a model
dxa.errors.missing-entity-suppress=${DXA_ERRORS_MISSING_ENTITY_SUPPRESS:true}
# Whether so suppress errors related to include page expansion in a page model
dxa.errors.missing-include-page-suppress=${DXA_ERRORS_MISSING_INCLUDE_PAGE_SUPPRESS:true}
## Tridion configuration
# Taxonomies
dxa.tridion.navigation.taxonomy.marker=${DXA_TRIDION_NAVIGATION_TAXONOMY_MARKER:[Navigation]}
dxa.tridion.navigation.taxonomy.type.structureGroup=${DXA_TRIDION_NAVIGATION_TAXONOMY_TYPE_SG:StructureGroup}
dxa.tridion.navigation.taxonomy.type.taxonomyNode=${DXA_TRIDION_NAVIGATION_TAXONOMY_TYPE_TAXNODE:TaxonomyNode}
dxa.tridion.navigation.taxonomy.type.page=${DXA_TRIDION_NAVIGATION_TAXONOMY_TYPE_PAGE:Page}
dxa.defaults.config-bootstrap-path=${DXA_DEFAULTS_CONFIG_BOOTSTRAP_PATH:/system/config/_all.json}
dxa.defaults.mappings-schemas=${DXA_DEFAULTS_MAPPINGS_SCHEMAS:/system/mappings/schemas.json}
dxa.defaults.config-dcp-uri-field=${DXA_DEFAULTS_CONFIG_DCP_URI_FIELD:dataPresentationTemplateUri}
```