# Tridion Sites 9.6 with DXA 2.2 and DXA Model Extension dxa.properties configuration update through Add-ons

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2, content-service

In Tridion 8.5 with DXA 2.0 with Model Service implementation, we had an option to control to keep trailing slash (/) when stripping index at the end of resolved links for the component link resolver in the model service.

It was done by applying the following flags in the dxa.properties:
dxa.web.link-resolver.keep-trailing-slash=${DXA_WEB_LINK_RESOLVER_KEEP_TRAILING_SLASH:true}

Now, we have upgraded to Tridion Sites 9.6 with DXA 2.2 and used the DXA model extension, and deployed via add-on service.
As per below reference,
[Tridion Sites 9.5 with DXA 2.2 and DXA Model Extension dxa.properties configuration](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/21683/tridion-sites-9-5-with-dxa-2-2-and-dxa-model-extension-dxa-properties-configurat?rq=1)

I can find the dxa.properties from udp-content-dxa-extension-11.6.0-1208.jar in the add-on DXA model extension package and just updated the flag value as true (DXA_WEB_LINK_RESOLVER_KEEP_TRAILING_SLASH:true) in dxa.properties and  uploaded again through add-ons.

Latest package was uploaded successfully, after I have restarted the content service. But the respective change is still not getting reflected in the website.

My question is how to update the dxa.properties configuration through add-ons in Tridion 9.6?

Does anyone have anything that might help me?

Comment: I have tried to create and update custom application.properties with required flag value change (dxa.web.link-resolver.keep-trailing-slash=${DXA_WEB_LINK_RESOLVER_KEEP_TRAILING_SLASH:true). And then added through add-ons with all below possible extension options.   
1. Application Data Configuration Extension
2. Content Service Model Transformer Extension
3. Mergeable Configuration Extension. But still the changes it's not getting reflected. Does anyone have anything that might help me?

Comment: It's duplicated question, as I mentioned in my answer you can pass and control those parameters for the content service startup parameters to override those settings values.